# What's the difference between these two HTML DOCTYPE declarations?

Tags: html, jsf-2, jsf-2.2, w3c

What's the difference between these two? I read that the first simply refers to a HTML5 page. What about the second one? Is there any real difference between the two? Thanks.

1. `<!DOCTYPE html>`
2. `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A document type declaration (DOCTYPE) tells the browser – or any other tool processing your document –  which version of HTML or XHTML your document is using.

There are many DOCTYPEs, because there are [many versions of HTML/XHTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Comparison_of_document_types) (e.g. HTML 4.01 (Transitional), HTML 4.01 (Strict), XHTML 1.0 (Strict), etc. However, as of HTML5, the only DOCTYPE you need to know and use is `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

The bottom line is you want to trigger [**standards mode** (as opposed to quirks mode)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode) in your browser when processing the document. Among your two options, just use #1, it's shorter and easier to remember.

Further reading:

- [Don't forget to add a doctype](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/Doctype)
- [Recommended Doctype Declarations to use in yoru Web document](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html)

Comment: But the declaration 2 is used in a JSF tutorial example. How is it different from <!DOCTYPE html> only? Is the 2nd declaration also a HTML5 declaration?

Comment: Older doctypes can still be used. But if you try to use new HTML5 elements in a document with an older DOCTYPE, you will get validation errors.

Comment: So you mean the 2nd one is an older doctype declaration, i.e. HTML4? It's used in a JSF example. Is a JSF file also a HTML file?

Comment: The first DOCTYPE in your list is the most modern, because HTML5 is the most modern. Selecting a DOCTYPE before HTML5 was an ambiguous and somewhat confusing process (there were many options). No longer. It's very simple, easy and straightforward now. Use #1 and you're set.

Comment: Based on this: http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html, to specify a doc is a JSF file, it's better to use the 1st declaration? Because it's explicitly says it is an XHTML file (JSF)?

Comment: If you have an XHTML file, and it is being served as XHTML (which I would think is very rare), then you need to use an XHTML doctype. When XHTML was in its prime years back, it was still being served mostly as `text/html`, so it was an HTML document nonetheless.

Comment: I was focusing my answer and comments on your question. I apologize I'm not familiar with JSF.